# How much space does a cat need?

Tags: cats

Im in short order moving into an apartment and my roommates arent big cat people so said cat would only have my room which id guess is about 200-230 sq ft. I would invest in a six foot cat tower for play, climbing and such. Would this be enough room or would it simply be unhealthy for a cat?

Comment: Does your room have a window that has a view of something active? a road/street or a park? looking at animated things is a good thing for any creature, even humans; when confined to such a small space. your room might be enough, but its the minimum imo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is doable if you provide enrichment for your cat, which it sounds like you plan on doing with the cat tower. It would not be unhealthy for the cat as long as she had enough room to climb and explore, and you play with her regularly. You might consider putting lots of empty shelves on the wall for her to climb around on – essentially increasing her "floor" space. Make sure the shelves are good and sturdy. For an indoor cat, the vertical space is almost as important as the horizontal space.

I would not recommend having a kitten in such a confined space, however an older cat may be perfectly content living in one room. It also depends what the cat is used to. A cat that is used to roaming large areas of the house and going outdoors chasing mice will likely have many more issues with being confined to one room.

The other thing to consider is *your* space. Keep in mind that things like the litter box and catfood may have to be near to your bed – are you okay with that? Also will your cat mind eating in the same room as her litter box – some cats are fussy that way.

Comment: Why would a kitten be a bad idea? Just curious, i thought that maybe if it grew up in a small space that maybe it would be so used to it that it wouldnt have a problem. However, i do see the fact that a kitten will have much much more energy.

Comment: @Kurt It depends on the kitten, but I just think a kitten would get easily bored being confined to one room and generally be more interested in exploring the "outside world" than an older cat. I'm also not sure I'd be able to sleep with a kitten running around the room all night. But that's not to say you might not have the same problems with an older cat too.